# Access protected data member via friend member function

Tags: c++, friend-function

EDIT:

The original program has multiple files as [shown in here](https://onlinegdb.com/ryXnGndBD)

I'm trying to access protected data member in my class from a friend member function of a different class.

I keep getting an access error:

> 9:32: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class b' 5:7: error:
> forward declaration of 'class b'  In member function 'void b::f(a*)':
> 12:13: error: 'int a::i' is protected 20:47: error: within this
> context

This is my code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class b;
class a{
    public:
    
    friend void b::f(a* pointer);
    
    protected:
    int i = 6;
    
    
    
};

class b{
    public:
    void f(a* pointer){std::cout<<pointer->a::i<<std::endl;}
    
    
};




int main()
{
  a a1;
  b b1;
  
  b1.f(&a1);
}
```

Comment: To declare `b::f()` as a `friend`, it is necessary that class `b` ALREADY have been defined.   A simple `class b` declaration is not enough.

Comment: @Peter but if both classes are co-dependent, how can I do it?

Comment: Place a declaration of class `a` before the definition of class `b`.  Then define class `b`  before class `a`, not after.    You'll also need to move the definition of `b::f()` so it is outside (not inline) the class definition.

Comment: "but if both classes are co-dependent, how can I do it?" change your design such that they do not depend on each other mutally. There are many solutions, depends on what is the actual aim...

Answer (score 3):

The issue is only superficially related to `friend`. It's rather due to circular dependencies of class definitions and member functions; `a` needs to know the definition of `b` because it refers to `b::f`. But the definition of `b::f` needs the definition of `a`, as it refers to `a::i`. Luckily, definitions of a class and its member functions can be separated from each other.

You can take the following measures to tackle this step by step:

1. declare `class a;`
2. define `class b { /* ... */ };`, but **without** defining its member functions (as they need access to `a`'s definition
3. define `class a { /* ... */ };`, possibly with inline member function definitions
4. and finally define `b`'s member functions.

This is how it looks like:

```
// Step 1:
class a;

// Step 2:   
class b{
    public:
    void f(a* pointer);
};

// Step 3:
class a{
    public:
    friend void b::f(a* pointer);
    
    protected:
    int i = 6;
};

// Step 4:
void b::f(a* pointer)
{
    std::cout<<pointer->a::i<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

[why it's not working in here?](https://onlinegdb.com/ryXnGndBD)

Comment: Because you misinterpreted step 1. You still have a circular dependency in your headers. `b.h` **includes** `a.h`, but it must **declare** `class a;` instead of including its full definition.

Answer (score 1):

At the point where you try to declare the method of `b` a friend via `friend void b::f(a* pointer);`, the class `b` is incomplete. You cannot refer to members yet. On the other hand, `b` only needs a forward declaration for `a`:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class a;
class b{
    public:
    void f(a* pointer);                
};

class a{
    public:        
    friend void b::f(a* pointer);        
    protected:
    int i = 6;
};

void b::f(a* pointer){std::cout<<pointer->a::i<<std::endl;}

int main()
{
  a a1;
  b b1;
  
  b1.f(&a1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You are trying to reference `b::f` before class `b` is defined.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class a;

class b{
    public:
    void f(a* pointer);
};
class a{
    public:
    
    friend void b::f(a* pointer);
    
    protected:
    int i = 6;        
};

void b::f(a* pointer)
{std::cout<<pointer->a::i<<std::endl;}






int main()
{
  a a1;
  b b1;
  
  b1.f(&a1);
}
```